# Can anyone tell me the translation of these words?

Tags: translation

[image]

Please i want to know the translation of the words written on this bracelet

Answer (score 2):

平安 means "safe", and 平安符 can be translated as "lucky charm" in English, which is something that can bring you luck.

Comment: So in all it means safe & luck ?

Comment: And what about the other face ?

Answer (score 1):

Left side : a usual creative magic charm drawing. (Any creative people can make one)

Right side : 平安符  it means Safety(平安) charm (符).

As usual, any magical charm will make people sick if it contains unsafe material or not cleaned constantly.